# magento not reading JS directory

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.8, mage

I have added the js files in

```
/skin/frontend/default/mytheme/js
```

and the local.xml file is in

```
/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout
```

The code to add the js is

```
    <reference name="head">
        <!--CSS-->
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/slicknav.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap-responsive.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/product-slider.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/fb_style.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/flexslider.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/jquery.selectbox.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/jquery.bxslider.css</name><params/></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name><params/></action>


        <!--JS-->
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/no-conflict.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/bootstrap.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.easing.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.mousewheel.pack.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.elastislide.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>jquery.flexslider.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery.tagsphere.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/retina-replace.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/retina-replace.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>js/js/jquery.bxslider.js</script></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>js/html5.js</name><params/><if>lte IE 8</if></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>js/html5.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>js/jquery.bxslider.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 9</if></action>
    </reference>
```

but, magento is not reading any of the above files.  I don't know if it is conflicting with any other `xml` file or any other **`javascript`** directory.

Any help please as I have this projct to be submitted in a day or two and could not figure out what it might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this structure:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js</name></action>
```

Comment: You should write in your question what the difference to the XML in the question is and why it works. Just in a short sentence. Just for a better style for future visitors.